# how to prevent splashscreen to appears when leaving an flutter application?

Tags: flutter

my splash screen appears 2 times: at the begining and at the end(when i logout). here is what i have done :
this is the page in which i indicate the differents routes and pages of my application

```
               Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Sign Up Screen ',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
         initialRoute: 'SplashScreen',
        routes: {
           'SignIn': (context) => SignInScreen(),
           'SignUp': (context) => SignUpScreen(),
           'Home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
           'Welcome': (context) => Welcome(),
           'package': (context) => Packages(),
           'CreateCampaign': (context) => CreateCampaign(),
           'CreatePub': (context) => CreatePub(),
           'SplashScreen': (context) => SplashScreen(),
        },
       );
        }
```

and here is a part of my splash screen code:

```
         class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
             @override
            void initState() {
            super.initState();
            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'SignIn');
         });
         }
```

Comment: Are you using any Root page(to check whether a user has already signed in or not)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` instead of `pushNamed` might work :

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, 'SignIn', (route) => false);
```

It should remove the `SplashScreen` from the route.

Comment: i noticed whit the Navigator.pushNamed method, the next page doesn't have the back icon, how can solve that pease?

Comment: Well, it's because there's no page to go back to. If you want to exit the app or some custom logic like logging out, create a custom button in the `leading` parameter of the `AppBar`.

Answer (score 0):

use when back pressed

onPressed: ()=> exit(0),